# Preconditions when setting contents for key using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, preconditions

On boto2, we can store an object using the name of Key object as the key and the preconditions (i.e. If-Match, If-None-Match, etc.) inside the headers dict parameter that will be sent with the PUT request.

Example:

```
# assume both bucket and key are created beforehand
fp_a = FakeWriteFile(file_size, 'A')
key.set_content_from_file(fp_a, headers={'If-Match': '*'})
```

Now for boto3, there are at least a couple of APIs that would let us put an object inside a bucket such as:

```
fp_a = FakeWriteFile(file_size, 'A')
bucket.Object('foo').put(Body=fp_a)
```

Alternatively, using low-level S3 client:

```
bucket.put_object(Key='foo', Body=fp_a)
```

For the two cases above on boto3, where would I need to add preconditions to ensure that those PUT requests are made through if they meet all the conditions, similarly to boto2's headers parameter with the preconditions set in?  I tried to find information on boto3 API DOC, but those preconditions are only set for GET operations: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

S3 actually ignores those parameters in a PUT request.